# Sites 9 licensing model

Tags: licensing, sites-9

Does anybody know how the licensing for Sites 9 works? The CM installer doesn't ask for a license at any point so I added my developer license manually after the installation just in case (don't know whether it was mandatory though, haven't tried it without).

Funnily enough, I can still open the CM even though the license has expired (my 8.5 CM instance displays the license expired message). Is the CM side not licensed in Sites 9? What about Content Porter? The online documentation has no info on this.

Comment: The licensing model is the same. You buy a number of CPUs and Servers and you’re allowed to run up to that number. The licensing _check_ might not be there in Sites 9, but I can’t confirm that.